# unable to upload an excel file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload, phpexcel, lamp

I have a Codeigniter project that can insert data into database through uploading an excel file and reading it with PHPExcel. It is working on my localhost however when I uploaded it in a LAMP server, It gives me an error **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.** How am I going to solve this?

**EDIT**
In my project, I also have a file image uploading..

```
 public function uploadConfig(){
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel');  
    $this->load->library('PHPExcel/IOFactory');
    $config['upload_path'] = './csv_uploads/'; 
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|csv|xls';
    $config['max_size'] = '10000'; 
    $config['overwrite'] = true;
    $config['encrypt_name'] = FALSE;
    $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);
    $this->upload->initialize($config);

    if (!is_dir('csv_uploads'))
    {
        mkdir('./csv_uploads', 0777, true);
    }
    // gif|jpg|jpeg|png
}
```

This works on my localhost in **XAMPP**. However, when I uploaded it on my **LAMP** server, it didn't work.

Comment: plz add bit of upload function code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Codeigniter : The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. Yesterday it was fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868995/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed-yesterda)

Comment: try checking allowed  mime type `$config['allowed_types'] = 'xls'`; is there

Comment: @vnpnlz, it is working on my localhost.

Comment: can you add this lines `'xlsx' => array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet','application/zip'),` to `application/config/mimes.php`

Comment: can you check result of `var_dump(print_r($_FILES));` put this in controller and tell

Comment: @vnpnlz, I do have something like that in mime.php.. the problem occured  when I uploaded it in the server which is LAMP.. but in my localhost, it is working and I am using XAMPP..

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0, this is the result: **Array ( [files] => Array ( [name] => Book1.xlsx [type] => application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpIj8rmv [error] => 0 [size] => 10618 ) )
boolean true
The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**

Comment: please check the php.ini file with below configuration with ; Whether to allow HTTP file uploads.
`file_uploads = On` is on or not may be lamp problem

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0, it is already **on**. And by the way, **.xls** file can be uploaded.. only the **.csv** and **.xlsx** can't be uploaded.

Comment: which version of codeigniter are you using and which OS?

Comment: @AnmolRaghuvanshiVersion1.0, I am using 2.1.3 and in my localhost, windows 8.1.. while on server, Turnkey lamp (linux)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93749/discussion-between-anmol-raghuvanshi-version-1-0-and-d-unknown).

Comment: Also, you are trying to upload file that is bigger than allowed (10000<10618).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For **The file type you are attempting to upload is not allowed** this issue  occur because of your file type is wrong or not fulfill.

Please apply below step to get your file type.

You can looking at system/libraries/Upload.php line 199:

```
$this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]);
```

Update that line to:

```
 $this->_file_mime_type($_FILES[$field]); var_dump($this->file_type); die();
```

Now you can see your actual file type  Like xlsx or csv or xls or ods

Now you can add your file type below code

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|csv|xls';
```

also add in  `config/mimes.php`

Comment: it only displaying **string 'application/vnd.ms-excel' (length=24)**

Comment: go to application/config/mimes.php and apply below changes                         'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel'),   to   array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/octet-stream'),

Comment: thank you for your help. I noticed that I should just add the string displayed to mimes.php that corresponds to the file extension to be uploaded..

Answer (score 3):

Codeigniter 3

add to your config/mimes.php types 'application/octet-stream'

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/octet-stream','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip')
```

then it will work

Answer (score 1):

Go to `config/mimes.php` -> lines no 32 (xls) -> add `'application/vnd.ms-office'` into existing array.

```
'xls'   =>  array('application/excel', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel', **'application/vnd.ms-office'**)
```

This work only for xls for any other type get the mime type and add into this array.

Answer (score 0):

**In** your code

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|csv|xls';
```

> But in U**buntu it save file types is *`ods`* format**. So it will never let allow to upload. add that

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|csv|xls|ods';
```

---

**And** in `config/mimes.php`

add this

```
'ods'   =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
```

---

**Provide Permeation to write** in the folder

```
sudo chown apache:apache -R /var/www/html
```

**and in `php.ini`**

1. Check ***`file_upload`*** is on
2. and check ***max upload limit***
3. as well as check ***max execution time***

Comment: @d_unknown check this

Comment: I checked the php.ini, added `ods` to mimes.php and allowed_type `ods`.. but it still didn't work..

Comment: I can actually upload a **.xls** file.. but not **.xlsx** and **.csv**.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using liberOffice or Open Office, You will face this problem. add "application/octet-stream" type in 'xlsx' to your application/config/mimes.php

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/octet-stream','application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip', 'application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msword', 'application/x-zip')
```

Answer (score -1):

In Your Code Add Below Line

```
 $config['allowed_types']        = '*';
 $config['detect_mime']          = false;
```

this is configuration setting.