# Unable to import xlsx file in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, file-type

after all the configuration if I am trying to import csv or xls file I am easily being able to do that but, the moment I am trying to import xlsx file gettig an error  'The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed'. In the file mimes.php

```
'xlsx'  =>  array('application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet', 'application/zip'),
```

getting error as '**The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed**'. Any suggestion will be appreciated thnx.

Comment: visit here [unable-to-upload-an-excel-file-in-codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427906/unable-to-upload-an-excel-file-in-codeigniter)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to upload an excel file in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33427906/unable-to-upload-an-excel-file-in-codeigniter)

Answer (score -1):

Please try with following

On upload function use

$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; //All Files

If it is working then Please check with $_FILES for what mime type your browser read for .xlsx file

Your can also check with another excel import (If all above solution is not working)
http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/

Answer (score -2):

> I think you also need to convert your file xlsx to xls or maybe you can save as it xls, and it will work sure.
>
> its working for me after save as xls. OR change your 'xls' parameter in config >> mimes.php file with below.

```
'xls'   =>  array('application/vnd.ms-excel', 'application/msexcel', 'application/x-msexcel', 'application/x-ms-excel', 'application/x-excel', 'application/x-dos_ms_excel', 'application/xls', 'application/x-xls', 'application/excel', 'application/download', 'application/vnd.ms-office', 'application/msword'),
```