# Codeigniter 3 does not upload jpeg image

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I have problem when i try to upload `jpeg` image. 
My configuration is :

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
```

And mimes:

```
'jpeg'  =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'),
```

All other formats like `gif, jpg, png` work fantastic, only not work when i try to upload `jpeg`

What can be problem? Anyone have some problem ?

Comment: print_r($this->upload->display_errors()); to debug the issue

Comment: show me your upload codes

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes the file extension does not tell the truth.
Check the real MIME type of the file. Use something like **exiftool**.
For example: You have `your_notjpg_file.jpg`, but this file's mime is `image/webp`,
then add this MIME Type to the jpg extension in config file:
`./application/config/mimes.php`.

```
'jpg'   =>  array('image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 'image/webp'),
```

Or rename that file before update to the correct extension, and be sure,
that this extension is in `mimes.php` and in your upload config:

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp';
```

I have had similar problem when I tried to upload some thumbnail images from Youtube.
All of them were with jpg extension.
As it turned out, jpg was not jpg, but webp.
This worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Bro. You made my day :-)

Answer (score -1):

Please try with

$config['allowed_types'] = '*'; //All Types of Images

If it is working then Please check with $_FILES for what mime type your browser read.

Same issue with file upload for .xls. Please check answer:

[Unable to import xlsx file in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37115180/unable-to-import-xlsx-file-in-codeigniter/37115861?noredirect=1#comment61800978_37115861)

Comment: Please check with $_FILES for mime type which is your browser read and update your mimes.php file which is located in ./application/config/mimes.php

Comment: So you are telling cant upload file with virus!! Evan can upload in jpeg format too

Comment: I am not telling about virus. Please upload .jpeg file and check mime type using $_FILES. On my end Chrome, FF and Safari .jpeg file return mime type is  [type] => image/jpeg