# How to Upload .webp Images

Tags: php, codeigniter, continuous-integration, codeigniter-3

I am new in CI.
I am trying to upload webp images using PHP CI Framework, Can anyone give me suggestion about how to upload .webp instead of jpg?

Comment: What are you having trouble with? Is there something special about uploading .webp files?

Comment: $config['allowed_types'] = '*'; //All Files//  Using this I got the result but please let me know there is another way to upload webp file type. thanks in advance.

Comment: Ok, and _what_ doesn't work? Do you get any errors? .webp files not selectable? Using what code?

Answer (score 4):

## .webp image uploading in CodeIgniter 3

- Add webp MIME Type in config file: ./application/config/mimes.php.
  'webp'   =>  array('image/webp'),
- And in your upload config "allowed_types" add "webp" :
  $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp';
- .webp image resizing, cropping, water marking
  goto https://github.com/shackeelck/webp_ci_3

Answer (score 1):

Add `webp` as a MIME type in the config file:

```
./application/config/mimes.php. 'webp'  =>  array('image/webp', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

And in your upload config `"allowed_types"` add `"webp"` :

```
$config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|jpeg|png|webp';
```

just add in the Mimes file

```
'webp'  =>  array('image/webp', 'application/octet-stream'),
```

then it works in `Codeigniter`

Answer (score -1):

You can use file upload function like this in CI4:

```
function upload() {
    helper(['form', 'url']);

    $database = \Config\Database::connect();
    $db = $database->table('TABLE NAME');

    $input = $this->validate([
        'file' => [
            'uploaded[file]',
            'mime_in[file,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp]',
            'max_size[file,1024]',
        ]
    ]);

    if (!$input) {
        print_r('Choose a valid file');
    } else {
        $img = $this->request->getFile('file');
        $img->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads');

        $data = [
           'name' =>  $img->getName(),
           'type'  => $img->getClientMimeType()
        ];

        $save = $db->insert($data);
        print_r('File has successfully uploaded');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code but I am using CI-3 so mime_type  webp not available

Comment: I think you might want to give a look [Codeigniter 3 does not upload jpeg image](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616391/10030431)

Comment: @MahmudHasanJion You can't just put it there and say it's a valid image. `'mime_in[file,image/jpg,image/jpeg,image/png,image/webp]'` it doesn't work