# Codeigniter: The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed

Tags: php, codeigniter, upload

I'm using CI latest version. **Got error while uploading a JPG files**. I use the code from here https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html and a little bit from [Multiple files upload in Codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20113832/multiple-files-upload-in-codeigniter)

The **Controller**:

```
$config = array(
'upload_path'   => 'path to upload',
'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg',
'overwrite'     => 0,
'max_size'      => 1024,                       
);
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config); // Make sure it has been initialized

if (!$this->upload->do_upload('gambar1')){
    $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    return $error;
}else{ echo 'success'; }
```

The **View**:

```
<?php echo form_open(base_url().'report/send', 'method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"', $hidden);?>
<input type="file" class="hidden" name="gambar1"></form>
```

When I'm trying to upload JPG files, it gives me **The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.**
Any idea?

Comment: Try using form_open_multipart() and `'upload_path'   => './uploads/',`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**
I've try to upload it to server. But it still gives me the same error. Then i found this: [Codeigniter : The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed. Yesterday it was fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868995/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed-yesterda)
"The most recent time I have had this is when I upgraded my core Codeiginter version from 2.x to 3.x. I updated the contents of the system directory, but not application/config. I didn't spot the fact that the application/config/mimes.php file is slightly different - the newer version returns an array whereas the old one included it as a var. **The fix was to copy in the newer version of mimes.php**"

Comment: I have the idential mimes. In fact I have the identical versions on localhost and online. They both worked a while back. Just now, I can't upload the Excel file online. Any clue? Thanks!

Comment: @itsols I ended up using `move_uploaded_file()` with my custom validation for file extensions.

Answer (score 2):

This might help

```
'allowed_types' => 'jpg|gif|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG',
```

print errors and see what it returns after this

Comment: still same, The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

Comment: filename length?

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/file_uploading.html#the-controller tried this code, works like a charm

Comment: I think the problem is on my pc (using win 7, wampserver), because i've tried the full code from ci user guide without edited, still not works and give the same error. I'll try on other server. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I figured out that the error came from the uploaded pictures.
If they were originally .png files and I changed them myself to .jpg, I would get this kind of error. The same happened when changing the mime type of any file.
What I did was put back the original mime type and it worked just fine.

Comment: I had the same problem where Dropzone.js is transforming them on the client and uploading .png as .jpg. Codeigniter complained about the filetype even though I'd set the `$config["allowed_types"] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';`. Setting the `"allowed_types" = '*'` gets CI to shut up.

Comment: @ourmandave . thank man. this helped me. i try to allow txt file not working. so i changed to * and it works

Answer (score 1):

i am faced same problem.......and find too much solution but no any solution worked for me........then i was try to use different method to upload and that is worked......CI Version is 3.1.10

here is your solution

$report_pdf = "";

```
    if (!empty($_FILES) && isset($_FILES["report_pdf"])) {

        $ext = pathinfo($_FILES['report_pdf']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
        $new_name = 'report_pdf_' . time() . '_' . $this->get_random_string(4) . '.' . $ext;
        $file_url = "uploads/" . $new_name;


        $config['file_name'] = $new_name . "." . $ext;
        $config['upload_path'] = "uploads/";
        $config['allowed_types'] = '*';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $_FILES['userfile2']['name'] = $new_name . "." . $ext; //$_FILES['songs']['name'][$i];
        $_FILES['userfile2']['type'] = $_FILES['report_pdf']['type'];
        $_FILES['userfile2']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['report_pdf']['tmp_name'];
        $_FILES['userfile2']['error'] = $_FILES['report_pdf']['error'];
        $_FILES['userfile2']['size'] = $_FILES['report_pdf']['size'];
        $this->upload->initialize($config);
        if ($this->upload->do_upload('userfile2')) {

            $finfo = $this->upload->data();
            $report_pdf = $file_url;
        } else {
            $error = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $result = array(
                'msg' => strip_tags($error)
            );
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

For PDF, CI3 mimes array don't have "application/octet-stream" in the config/mimes.php file. Add "application/octet-stream" in the pdf key. Works fine.