# Cannot set new image name in codeigniter

Tags: image, codeigniter, model-view-controller, codeigniter-3, codeigniter-2

I'm uploading multiple image in codeigniter, But when i set new name using this code  `$_FILES['attachment']['name']= $filename;`

**I'm getting**

> The filetype you are attempting to upload is not allowed.

**Please suggest solution to solve this issue.**

```
public function do_upload()
{
    if (($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) == "POST") {
        $count = count($_FILES['attach_file']['name']);
        $files = $_FILES;
        for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        $filename = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$i];
        $filename = strstr($filename, '.', true);
        $email    = $this->session->userdata('email');
        $filename = strstr($email, '@', true)."_".$filename;
        $filename = strtolower($filename);

        $_FILES['attachment']['name']= $filename;
        $_FILES['attachment']['type']= $_FILES['attach_file']['type'][$i];
        $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']= $_FILES['attach_file']['tmp_name'][$i];
        $_FILES['attachment']['error']= $_FILES['attach_file']['error'][$i];
        $_FILES['attachment']['size']= $_FILES['attach_file']['size'][$i];    
        $config['upload_path']   = FCPATH .'./assets/attachments/new/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf|doc|docx|bmp|gif|jpg|jpeg|jpe|png';
        $config['max_size']      = 0;
        $config['max_width']     = 0;
        $config['max_height']    = 0;
        $config['encrypt_name']  = true; 
        $config['file_ext_tolower'] = true; 
        $config['overwrite']     = false;
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('attachment')) {
            $data['exception'] = $this->upload->display_errors();
            $data['status'] = false;
            echo json_encode($data);
        } else {
            $upload =  $this->upload->data();
            $data['message'] = 'upload_successfully';
            $data['filepath'] = './assets/attachments/'.$upload['file_name'];
            $data['status'] = true;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }  
    }
}
```

Comment: which file type you are uploading??

Comment: @KUMAR: I'm uploading jpeg type file

Comment: please remove `$config['max_size'] = 0;`   `$config['max_width']     = 0;`
        `$config['max_height']    = 0;`  & let me know.

Comment: which version are you using: CI 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @KUMAR: removed code but getting same error

Comment: @Vickel: I'm using version 3.x of Codeigniter

Comment: you might need to update mime-types, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21868995/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed-yesterda, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43024959/codeigniter-the-filetype-you-are-attempting-to-upload-is-not-allowed

Comment: @Vickel: when i print filename it gives me name of the file,  $_FILES['attachment']['name']= $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$i]; this is working but i want to give it a different name

Comment: try with `$config["allowed_types"] ="*";`

Comment: i want to give it a different name means??

Comment: @KUMAR: I want to change the image name before file upload,  $filename contains the new name that i want to save

Comment: @user3653474 the uploaded file name is in the folder is changes or not??

Comment: @user3653474 now what happens??

Answer (score 0):

**Note:-** You are assign same variable name again & again `$filename`

**Please Change this:-**

```
$filename = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$i];
$filename = strstr($filename, '.', true);
$email    = $this->session->userdata('email');
$filename = strstr($email, '@', true)."_".$filename;
$filename = strtolower($filename);

$_FILES['attachment']['name']= $filename;
```

**to :-**

```
$filename = $_FILES['attach_file']['name'][$i];
$filename1 = strstr($filename, '.', true);
$email    = $this->session->userdata('email');
$filename2 = strstr($email, '@', true)."_".$filename1;
$filename3 = strtolower($filename2);
```

Comment: Tried the above code but getting same issue when i pull $config["allowed_types"] ="*"; then a plain files gets uploaded without any extension

Comment: @user3653474 the uploaded file name is in the folder is changes or not??

Comment: @KUMAR- No it doen't change the image file name

Comment: @user3653474 you want to change both `uploaded image name` & `table insert name` before insertion??

Comment: @user3653474 just echo `$filename3 = strtolower($filename2);` what it returns same file name or different??

Comment: It returns info_desert which is the new name of file